# Difference between hh:mm a and HH:mm a

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, java-6

Here is my original code-

```
String dateString = "23 Dec 2015 1:4 PM";
Locale locale = new Locale("en_US");
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm a");
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm a", locale);
Date date = null;

try {
    date = formatter.parse(dateString);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    LOGGER.error(e);
}

String newDate = df.format(date);
System.out.println("oldDate = " + dateString);
System.out.println("newDate = " + newDate);
```

and here is my output-

```
oldDate = 23 Dec 2015 1:4 PM
newDate = 23 Dec 2015 01:04 AM
```

There is **AM-PM difference** between the `oldDate` and `newDate`. Now I changed the `DateFormat` code to-

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm a");
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm a", locale);
```

and I get the expected output, which is-

```
oldDate = 23 Dec 2015 1:4 PM
newDate = 23 Dec 2015 01:04 PM
```

I'm aware that `HH` signifies the **24 hour** format and `hh` signifies the **12-hour** format.

**My question is**

If I use `HH:mm a` instead of `hh:mm a`, shouldn't this be returning the time in **24-hour** format?

(or)

If it defaults to **12-hour** format, shouldn't it return respective AM/PM marker depending on the date input provided?

This is just for my understanding.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

Here the problem is with `Program flow`

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm a");
```

this `simple date formatter` is used to format the date string the **Date object** is created, here is the important part of answer

As you are using **HH** instead of **hh**, the **SimpleDateFormater** considers that provided date string is in `24-Hour Format` and simply **ignores** the `AM/PM marker` here.

The Date Object from constructed from this SimpleDateFormatter is passed to the

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm a", locale);
```

That's why it's printing

```
newDate = 23 Dec 2015 01:04 AM
```

if you change the line

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm a");
```

with

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm a");
```

Everything will go smooth as it should!

**Note** : when creating a locale you should pass the language code to the Locale() constructor. `en-us` not `en_us`.

**IMP** : Code is tested on **Java 8** also. `Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)`

Comment: Thanks @MenoHochschild. Kindly have a look at my answer once again!

Comment: Well better, but recommending `new Locale("en-us")` is still wrong.

Comment: @MenoHochschild with all due respect I would like to know you we can construct a Locale in `Java 8 (1.8.0_121)` from language as stated in my answer!

Comment: Kindly refer to the code snippet from java 8 package `java.util.Locale` at line number `700` which clearly states we can construct Locale from language. I am referring to `java 8 (1.8.0-121)`

Comment: I have even used 1.8.0-131. The problem is: "en-us" is only a language code and does not point to the country US (method `getCountry()` is empty!). Obviously, "en-us" is somehow interpreted just as English somewhere in the deep stack of JRE and therefore makes you think it would work. And the API is pretty clear, the one-parameter-locale-constructor only uses a pure language parameter... not the country. This matters if for example the country-dependent week-rules have to be determined - different in US or UK.

Answer (score 12):

**Difference between hh:mm and HH:mm:**

```
  HH:mm => will look like 00:12, 23:00... this has 24 hour format.

  hh:mm => will look like 01:00Am, 02:00Am,...01:00pm this has 12 hour format.
```

And the `a` in hh:mm a or in  HH:mm a is Am/pm marker for more info go to [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 1):

A simple test is the best answer to how the pattern "HH:mm a" is interpreted. First let us investigate the **printing mode**:

**The old format engine `SimpleDateFormat`:**

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(2015, 3, 1, 17, 45);
SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a", Locale.US);
System.out.println(sf.format(cal.getTime())); // 17:45 PM
```

**Java-8 (with the new package `java.time.format`):**

```
LocalTime time = LocalTime.of(17, 59);
DateTimeFormatter tf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm a", Locale.US);
System.out.println(tf.format(time)); // 17:59 PM
```

Here **we don't observe any override** in both cases. I prefer that approach because using the combination of "HH" and "a" is in my opinion rather an indication for a programming error (the user has obviously not thought enough about the meaning and official description of those pattern symbols).

Now let us investigate the **parsing mode** (and we will use strict mode to observe what is really going behind the scene):

```
String dateString = "23 Dec 2015 1:4 PM";
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy H:m a", Locale.US);
df.setLenient(false);
Date date = df.parse(dateString);
// java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "23 Dec 2015 1:4 PM"
```

How is the behaviour in Java-8? It is the same but with a clearer error message:

```
DateTimeFormatter tf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H:m a", Locale.US);
tf = tf.withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);
LocalTime.parse("1:4 PM", tf);
// DateTimeException: Cross check failed: AmPmOfDay 0 vs AmPmOfDay 1
```

This message tells us that the parsed hour (in 24-hour format!) with value "1" indicates AM while the text input contains the other parsed AM/PM-value "PM". This ambivalence cannot be resolved.

**Lesson: We have to be careful with lenient parsing where contradictious information can be ignored and lead to false assumptions.** The accepted answer of @Arjun is completely wrong.

By the way: Please use `Locale.US` or `new Locale("en", "US")` instead of `new Locale("en-US")` because the language "en-US" does not exist.

Comment: Hello @MenoHochschild kindly have a look at the answer! Thank you for your constructive criticism! I would like to hear from you!