# Incorrect date parsing with SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I've got a MySQL table with a date() and time() columns like

```
CREATE TABLE `vol` (
  `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `DEPART_DATE_VOL` date NOT NULL,
  `DEPART_HEURE_VOL` time NOT NULL,
  `ARRIVEE_DATE_VOL` date NOT NULL,
  `ARRIVEE_HEURE_VOL` time NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I need to query rows using the date() in the WHERE clause so I won't have a datetime() or timestamp (also, I can't modify the DB)

When getting the info in my DAO, I concat the date and time columns to parse a Java Date like:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
addon.setDateDepart(sdf.parse(rs.getString(DEPART_DATE_VOL) + " " + rs.getString(DEPART_HEURE_VOL)));
addon.setDateArrivee(sdf.parse(rs.getString(ARRIVEE_DATE_VOL) + " " + rs.getString(ARRIVEE_HEURE_VOL)));
```

For a row with departure date:

- 2018-02-26   10:50:00 the resulting Java date is correct

But for the arrival date:

- 2018-02-26   12:20:00 the resulting Java date is set to **2018-02-26T00:20:00**

**TMP Solution**

For now, I'll stick to

```
addon.setDateDepart(new LocalDateTime(rs.getString(DEPART_DATE_VOL) + "T" + rs.getString(DEPART_HEURE_VOL)).toDate());

addon.setDateArrivee(new LocalDateTime(rs.getString(ARRIVEE_DATE_VOL) + "T" + rs.getString(ARRIVEE_HEURE_VOL)).toDate());
```

which seems to work, altough I'm not sure if I will run into timezone problems...

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: You're using `hh`, which is for 12-hour based clocks. Use `kk` instead for 24-hour clocks. But yes you should try to use `java.time` instead. :)

Comment: In your workaround you are using `LocalDateTime` — from Joda-Time? That’s already better than the old Java date and time classes.

Comment: It's hard to understand why is behavior like that. I am curious also. What's coming to my mind is **Synchronization**, although there are no multiple threads in your code (DAO is to blame?). *Date formats are not synchronized. It is recommended to create separate format instances for each thread. If multiple threads access a format concurrently, it must be synchronized externally.* I really wish to know is this a case in your example.

Comment: With Java 8 or later and a JDBC 4.2 compliant JDBC driver you should be able to do `LocalDateTime.of(rs.getObject(DEPART_DATE_VOL, LocalDate.class), rs.getObject(DEPART_HEURE_VOL, LocalTime.class))`.

Comment: And you are right in worrying about time zone…

Comment: This should be helpful: [Common mistakes in date/time formatting and parsing](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2015/05/05/common-mistakes-in-datetime-formatting-and-parsing/). And this question: [Difference between hh:mm a and HH:mm a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34431260/difference-between-hhmm-a-and-hhmm-a/34431361).

Comment: Unfortunately I must stick to JDK6, thus the usage of (yes) joda.time

Comment: If you’re happy with Joda-Time, using it is a good idea. It’s not my home field, but I believe it can parse your date string and time string from the database just as easily as `java.time` can? In case you do want to upgrade within Java 6, `java.time` has been backported to Java 6 and 7, so you can get [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and use `java.time`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `HH:mm:ss` for the time part. `hh` is used for "Hour in am/pm (1-12)", see the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: Of course! As usual, just skipping the most obvious :/

Comment: @luso  Ultimately, you’d be better off using smart objects instead of dumb strings. See the [other Answer, by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48793182/642706) for the modern solution.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use `timestamp` datatype in your database instead of separate columns for date and for time. A MySQL `timestamp` is in UTC, so should avoid any time zone issues on the database side.
2. Use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. The old date and time classes like `Date` are poorly designed, and `SimpleDateFormat` in particular is notoriously troublesome, so avoid it.
3. Transfer date-time objects between your Java program and your database, not strings.

Read more [in this question: Java Best Practice for Date Manipulation/Storage for Geographically Diverse Users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40075780/java-best-practice-for-date-manipulation-storage-for-geographically-diverse-user). If you cannot do all of this, do as much as you can.

### Details

If you can store timestamps in your database, you can retrieve them as `java.time.Instant`:

```
Instant departVol = rs.getObject(DEPART_INSTANT_VOL, Instant.class);
```

If you cannot change the type that `addon.setDateDepart()` accepts, convert to a `Date` like this:

```
addon.setDateDepart(Date.from(departVol));
```

Or in the version using the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7:

```
addon.setDateDepart(DateTimeUtils.toDate(departVol));
```

If you cannot change the database design, you can still retrieve `java.time` objects from it:

```
LocalDate departDateVol = rs.getObject(DEPART_DATE_VOL, LocalDate.class);
LocalTime departHeureVol = rs.getObject(DEPART_HEURE_VOL, LocalTime.class);
LocalDateTime departDateHeureVol = LocalDateTime.of(departDateVol, departHeureVol);
```

The conversion to an old-fashioned `Date` is shaky, because as you say, there might be a time zone issue. Try:

```
addon.setDateDepart(
        Date.from(departDateHeureVol.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()));
```

If there seems to be a time zone issue here, you need to specify the correct time zone instead of `ZoneId.systemDefault()`.

If your Java version or JDBC driver doesn’t support getting the right date-time objects from your result set, parsing the strings is straightforward with the modern classes:

```
LocalDate departDateVol = LocalDate.parse(rs.getString(DEPART_DATE_VOL);
LocalTime departHeureVol = LocalTime.parse(rs.getString(DEPART_HEURE_VOL);
```

With these objects continue as above.

PS I haven’t tested my code snippets. If there’s a typo and you cannot fix it yourself, please revert.

### What went wrong in your code?

[kevmo314 is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48789557/incorrect-date-parsing-with-simpledateformat/48793182#comment84581073_48789557) that lowercase `hh` in your format pattern string is for hour with AM or PM, from 1 through 12. So `12:20:00` *does* mean `00:20:00`. To interpret `12` on a 24 hour clock, use uppercase `HH` for hour of day from 0 through 23.

**Link:** [ThreeTen backport Home](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/)